# Why is this JavaScript code invalid in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, string

I accidentially typed in \s instead of " ",

```
while(cname.charAt(cname.length-1) == "\s")
```

Aren't special characters resolved in all string literals?

Also, what is a proper regular expression to cut off all tabs and spaces from EOL?
The `my /(.*)[\s\t]/` selector just won't work! So I had to fallback to `while(if.. substr)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\s` is only a character class for spaces, tabs and newlines in a regular expression. "\s" becomes just "s" in this case.

Removing tabs and spaces from EOL with:

```
cname = cname.replace(/\s+$/mg, '');
```

- `\s+` matches one or more spaces or tabs
- `$` matches the end of the subject
- The `m` flag causes `$` to match the end of a line, and not the string.
- the `g` flag causes all matches to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

`\s` is legal syntax within a regex, but it is not legal syntax within a string.

This is fine:

```
/\s/
```

This is illegal:

```
"\s"
```